# How to help infer the type for generic vector when comparing equality

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```rust
struct HeadTail<T>(T, Vec<T>);

fn head_tail<T : Clone>(v: &Vec<T>) -> Option<HeadTail<T>> {
    match v.len() {
        0 => None,
        _ => {
            let mut tmp_v = v.clone();
            let head = tmp_v.remove(0);
            Some(HeadTail(head, tmp_v))
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn head_tail_many() {
    let vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let result = head_tail(&vec);

    match result {
        None => unreachable!(),
        Some(HeadTail(head, tail)) => {
            assert_eq!(1, head);
            assert_eq!(3, tail.len());
            assert_eq!([2, 3, 4], tail);
        }
    };
}
```

[Online demo with the problem](http://is.gd/GM2G3o)

And it fails with the following exception:

```
<std macros>:5:8: 5:33 error: the trait `core::cmp::PartialEq<collections::vec::Vec<_>>` is not implemented for the type `[_; 3]` [E0277]
<std macros>:5 if ! ( * left_val == * right_val ) {
```

Why can Rust not infer the type in this case?

What can I do to let it know it's any numeric type (eg `u8`)?

Comment: @Shepmaster it compiles because you don't run tests. If you try to run it properly or move the test code to `main()` you'll see the error: http://is.gd/GM2G3o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's useful to [create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when debugging these types of things. Here's an example:

```
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    assert_eq!([1,2,3,4], vec);
}
```

With the error

```
<std macros>:5:8: 5:33 error: the trait `core::cmp::PartialEq<collections::vec::Vec<_>>` is not implemented for the type `[_; 4]` [E0277]
<std macros>:5 if ! ( * left_val == * right_val ) {
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So, there's some kind of error with `PartialEq`, let's try to reduce further:

```
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    [1,2,3,4] == vec;
}
```

With the same basic error:

```
<anon>:3:5: 3:21 error: the trait `core::cmp::PartialEq<collections::vec::Vec<_>>` is not implemented for the type `[_; 4]` [E0277]
<anon>:3     [1,2,3,4] == vec;
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The `_` in `Vec<_>` means an as-yet-undermined type. Let's use explicit types to see if that's the problem:

```
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1u8, 2, 3, 4];
    [1u8,2,3,4] == vec;
}
```

Nope, still the same error:

```
<anon>:3:5: 3:23 error: the trait `core::cmp::PartialEq<collections::vec::Vec<u8>>` is not implemented for the type `[u8; 4]` [E0277]
<anon>:3     [1u8,2,3,4] == vec;
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Let's try flipping things around:

```
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1u8, 2, 3, 4];
    vec == [1u8,2,3,4];
}
```

Hmm. This works! Swapping the order in your original code also works.

Of course, the big question left is **why**. Let's look at the [docs for `Vec`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html), specifically the section about `PartialEq`:

```
impl<'a, 'b, A, B> PartialEq<[B; 4]> for Vec<A>
    where A: PartialEq<B>
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &[B; 4]) -> bool { ... }
}
```

So, you can test a `Vec<A>` to an `&[B; 4]` for equality, if you can test `A` and `B` for equality. What about the other way around? The [docs for arrays](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html) don't mention `Vec` at all (which makes sense, as they are more of a core feature), and there aren't any inverse implementations of `PartialEq`. This certainly seems surprising, and I have no good explanation for why they aren't there...

Ah, it appears this happened in [this commit](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/5cf126ae2f6af1cdac901f6995e3c2bab35e587f). Here's the commit message:

> The primary implementation which was lost was the ability to compare
>   `&[T]` and `Vec<T>` (in that order).
>
> This change also modifies the `assert_eq!` macro to not consider
>   both directions of equality, only the one given in the left/right
>   forms to the macro. This modification is motivated due to the fact
>   that `&[T] == Vec<T>` no longer compiles, causing hundreds of errors
>   in unit tests in the standard library (and likely throughout the
>   community as well).

[Manishearth found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282497/how-to-help-infer-the-type-for-generic-vector-when-comparing-equality/30282603?noredirect=1#comment48665123_30282603) a [comprehensive blog post](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2015/01/14/little-orphan-impls/) that describes the rationale behind this change in good detail!

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @Shepmaster's answer, the issue here is that the implementation for the `==` operator is asymmetric in this case. We have an `impl PartialEq<Vec<T>> for [T; n]`, but not the reverse. Perhaps we should have a reverse implementation, but generic array types aren't well supported yet.

This wasn't an issue with inference at all, it was an issue of comparing two different types and Rust not having a symmetric implementation.

Comment: Do you recall if this was a deliberate decision? It seems like we could add a few lines to the macros that generate all those methods for the reverse easily.

Comment: @Shepmaster I don't know; but if it was deliberate I suspect it's because generic impls for arrays are hard.

Comment: @Shepmaster I can only find `impl<A, B> PartialEq<[B]> for [A] where A: PartialEq<B>`. I suspect autoref/autoderef/coercions are at play here.

Comment: I found [the commit](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/5cf126ae2f6af1cdac901f6995e3c2bab35e587f), but will readily admit I'm not fully grokking the problem that was worked around.

Comment: @Shepmaster Uh, yeah, complicated bit of history there. [This](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2015/01/14/little-orphan-impls/) might help :)